# Finding the equation of the bisector

Tags: geometry

Given the following line equations:
$$ AB: x+2y-1=0$$ $$BC:2x-y+1=0$$
$$AC:2x+y-1=0$$ (which determine ABC triangle) How do I find the equation of the bisector?

Comment: This question is ambiguous as it currently stands.  By *bisector*, do you mean angle bisector, perpendicular bisector, etc.?

Comment: Bisector of what?

Comment: angle bisector of B

Answer (score 1):

The bisector of $ABC$ is the locus of points $(x,y)$ that their distance from 
$AB$ and $BC$ is equal, that is 
$$
\frac{|x+2y-1|}{\sqrt{1^2+2^2}}=\frac{|2x-y+1|}{\sqrt{1^2+2^2}}.
$$
Hence 
$$
x+2y-1=\pm(2x-y+1).
$$
This gives you the lines $x-3y+2=0$ and $3x+y=0$. Note that we got two lines since the angle have two bisectors. You can determine the right bisector by the position of the triangle.